# Using font icon in assets catalog

Tags: ios, xcode

I know it's possible to use a `svg` icon in the `assets catalog` of an iOS app. I also know it's possible to use font icons in iOS as easy as using a custom font and characters will be our icons.

But, some views don't have text attributes or don't support custom fonts.
For example, a `UIBarItem`.

Can we use font icons in the `assets catalog` so we can use them everywhere as an universal image, like a `svg` image?

Comment: What's your question? So far you've just made a bunch of statements but have not asked a question.

Comment: @rmaddy actually the paragraph that start with "as a solution if we can .." is what i'm trying to do !